# Checking whether an object exists in SCCM using vbScript

Tags: vbscript, sccm

I have a list of computer names stored in an vbscript array and need check whether these have an object in SCCM or not.

I have tried using a query similar to:
**set accounts = sQbemServices.ExecQuery("select * FROM SMS_R_System WHERE name = '" & testForName & "'")**    to look through SCCM.  This works ok as long as the computer names are valid, but once it reaches an invalid name, it seems to stop.  I have tried outputting the error number, but this always returns a '0' and checking if the result is null, but this doesn't work.

Is this the best way to check that a computer object exists and, if so, can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong please?  If not, any pointers would be much appreciated.

Comment: This might be a silly question, but does testForName contain apostrophes? (')

Answer (score 0):

`SWbemServices.ExecQuery` normally returns a `SWbemObjectSet`. If your query finds a valid computer then `accounts.Count` should be 1 or more, otherwise 0. Eg:

```
If (accounts.Count > 0) Then 
    WScript.Echo "Found Computer in SCCM"
Else
    WScript.Echo "Computer is not in SCCM"
End If
```

For more information about `SWbemServices`:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa393866(v=vs.85).aspx